# Rendering of umlauts (åäö) in IE8 and IE9 with Verdana

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, fonts, internet-explorer-9

Have this strange problems on some pages that rendering of umlauts (åäö) gets wrong in IE8 and IE9, sometimes. The encoding is utf-8 (mostly of the site works so I know it's correct) and I have tried to narrow down the css-classes and it seems that Verdana is only affected. Tried different computers as well.

I thougth I could be the meta X-UA-Compatible-related and changed to this tag with no luck.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

This is what it should look like:

[image]

And this is the result in IE8 and IE9

[image]

Comment: Is this a problem at any font size/weight?

Comment: If you change the encoding to latin1 of the delivered HTML file (and set the tags appropriately), does it work correctly? Could you show us a HTML sample (simple) file where this occurs?

Comment: Have a link to a page? I never saw behaviour like this in IE8 and I want to see for myself.

Comment: Yes, looks like a font rendering bug in IE, but it surprises me that this occurs in 9 as well. 8 was pretty bad, but 9 is slightly better. A link would be helpful :)

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved with ctrl + 0 (zoom reset to default) because I used ctrl- once and stupid IE render always with that zoom in (ctrl-). Hope will work.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I appreciate it. Here's a link to the acutal page: http://www.vbm.se/tidskriften/vb-2011/puff-1104.html and most of the site works. I think the encoding is correct. Tried to reset the zoom with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem manifests itself because, although the text is encoded in valid UTF-8, the **decomposed** Unicode normalization form is used, see [Unicode equivalence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence). It seems that on Windows many fonts work best when using usual single precomposed characters, not the sequences of base letters with combining diacritical marks separately followed.

For example, let's take a look at the word `från` with a hex editor.

On your site it's encoded as `66 72 61 CC 8A 6E` (i.e. latin small letters `f`, `r`, `a`, then `U+030A` code point representing *combining ring above*, then `n`).

But in Windows the usual encoding would be `66 72 C3 A5 6E` (i.e. latin small letters `f`, `r`, `å`, `n`). So the letter `å` would normally be represented by a single code point `U+00E5` (not by the sequence `U+0061, U+030A`).

If you are using PHP, try normalizing the text with the [Normalizer class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) first (just be sure the `intl` extension is installed).

Comment: This was it. I used the following:


$normlizer = new \Normalizer();

$content = $normlizer->normalize($content, \Normalizer::FORM_C);


Basically FORM_C and FORM_KC work well for fixing the issue.